# Incorrect selected tool circle. box. or lasso

Tags: mesh, vertices, select, tools

When I select vertices, edges, or polygons with the circle, box, or lasso tool in *Edit Mode*, spontaneous vertices are selected all over the mesh.

example:
[image]

I select the vertices on the legs, and the vertices are selected throughout the mesh.

Comment: If I selected vertices, edges, or polygons, with circle, box, or lasso tools, on head mesh, then automaticly selected vertices on all mesh! On foots, or bodyes, hands! Why? this error happens on any mesh! Even if you started the blender and added a sphere, or something else!

Comment: What if you change system/selection/opengl mode(s) option(s) in the preferences?

Comment: I selected all possible options, but the problem did not dare.

Comment: ok, so try anti aliasing options, a bit below (in "window draw method"). Though this may require to restart Blender. First try to turn it off: "No multisample"

Comment: quite sure I've encountered it in the past. Should be around OpenGl, antialiasing... can you confirm this does not happen in wireframe mode?

Comment: I don’t know what exactly I did on your advice, but the problem was solved! Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm so happy) Thanks!!!

Comment: Happy for you too!!